# eCommerce SEO: Unique"ify" my Product Names / URL's / description ,etc?

Tags: seo, ecommerce, meta-tags, meta-description, alt-attribute

Let's say you have 6-10 eCommerce sites all selling (mostly) the same products.  They use the same database to pull:

```
-descriptions
-titles
-keywords
-alt attributes
-unique urls
-etc.
```

My question is will this result in a penalty from Google for all these sites?  They are under different domain names.

Comment: Please define your question, identical to other sites? give examples and so forth - also please ensure this isn't duplicate by search for duplicate content in the search box as many concerns over duplicate elements such as metas have been asked again and again on Pro Webmasters.

Answer (score 1):

If the sites essentially have the same content, then you're probably going to run into duplicate content issues. Having the same content across domains is exactly what Google doesn't want.

You should use canonical URLs for the common products.